# Laravel 6 config mail dynamic problem at job using ShouldQueue

Tags: php, queue, laravel-6

I have a listener which implement ShouldQueue, the listener is handling a mail sending when event occurs. The job detects which type of user gets the email and config the mail sender name :

```
$displayName = $user->is_type() == 1 ? 'sender_name1' : 'sender_name2';

config(['mail.from' =>
                    [
                        'name' =>  $displayName
                    ]]);
```

On multiple actions the sender name is sent incorrectly even though the config occurs.
By printing getmypid() looks like the job runs on a process that already took care of
an older job and the sender name that used was of the older one.

Any suggestions for a solution please?